extending Users model
class Cyclist extends User

{

protected $table = 'users';


protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('cyclist', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('is_active', 'ok');
    });
}

Now when i do
$l = Cyclist::query()
  ->join('cyclist_table','cyclist_table.user_id','=','users.id')
  ->first();

dd($l);

Tinkerwell doesnt return anything. What am i missing in the child class?

Change ->first() to ->toSql() to see the actual query you're running, then see if there are actually any results that match in your Database. Sidenote, I'm not sure if this is a problem with your Cyclist extends User class; I've never seen this approach to Models in Laravel, and I'm not 100% what (or why) you're doing (it).

Not exactly clear why you'd expect data to show? Can e.g. run the equivalent SQL query and let us know if you do see data?  I.e. are there any users which are associated with the cyclist_table that also have the is_active value equal to ok?

@TimLewis my user class is way too long now 3k lines of code so i thought id extend the class . The query does return data in sequel ace..

@apokryfos The sql version is a select * from users table . It should still return a collection even if it returns all data.. this is just a start of something i just needed something to be returned if i do an extension of User

But you added a global scope, that is added to the query isn't it?

->first() can return null if it doesn't find a matching row... Your statement "It should still return a collection" would only apply if you used ->get(), and even then, that Collection may be empty. You might ned to edit your question with more details; there's some mismatch between your code and what we're seeing (or expecting to see based on your current code)...
